# How can I simulate a bunch of random clicks on a react webapp using selenium?

Tags: reactjs, selenium-webdriver

Currently, I'm trying to write a code in selenium that simulates random clicks in a web app. Something similar to how gremlinsjs does their clicker function.

Is there any way to do this with js?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("a");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var element = elements[I];

  element.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // do something here
  });
}
```